# IOS app cannot HTTP post to a form on a aspx site

Tags: asp.net, ios, authentication, http-post, viewstate

I am creating an app to login to a website instead of using a browser using HTTP post. I am using AFHTTPClient to handle all my post parameters.

Using Charles Proxy and accessing the site normally through Chrome I was able to pick up all the post parameters for the post string. Unfortunately every time I do a post to login, Charles proxy is showing a __ViewState being passed through as well and this changes for every login. I understand a viewstate is there as a hidden form item, so a user does not have to enter all the fields again if they are redirected back to the form in a browser.

My question is, how can I capture the __viewstate string and pass it through the post string every time I login? Storing an old __viewstate and using it every time I login is causing a login error sent back by the server.

p.s I do not have access to the server implementation.

Any help is much appreciated!